# MediaRecorder RecordedChunks Empty Issue in React Component - Unable to get Recorded Audio

Tags: reactjs, audio, audio-recording, voice, mediarecorder

**Problem:**
I'm encountering an issue with a React component responsible for recording and sending voice notes. Inside the `handleSend` function, I'm attempting to reply with the recorded audio file. However, I've noticed that the `recordedChunks` state, intended to store the recorded audio data, is empty within this function, leading to the failure of `reply([file])`.

**Code Overview:**

- The React component utilizes the `MediaRecorder` API to record audio.
- `recordedChunks` state is utilized to accumulate recorded audio data chunks.
- Upon calling `handleSend`, which should dispatch the recorded audio, it checks if `recordedChunks` has data, but it's found empty at this point.

**Expectations:**
I expect `handleSend` to send the recorded audio file via the `reply` function. However, due to `recordedChunks` being empty, the file isn't sent, leading to unexpected behavior.

**Request for Assistance:**
I'm seeking guidance on how to ensure that `recordedChunks` contains the recorded audio data within the `handleSend` function. Any insights into why `recordedChunks` might be empty at this stage and how to rectify it would be greatly appreciated.

**Code Snippet:**

```js
function Voicenote({ reply }) {
  const mediaRecorderRef = useRef(null);
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);
  const [recordedChunks, setRecordedChunks] = useState([]);
  const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState([]);
  const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(false);

  const handleOnClick = async () => {
    if (!isRecording) {
      setIsRecording(true);
      setRecordedChunks([]);

      const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(
        await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          audio: true,
        })
      );

      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
        if (e.data.size > 0) {
          setRecordedChunks((prev) => [...prev, e.data]);
        }
      };

      mediaRecorder.start();
      mediaRecorderRef.current = mediaRecorder;
    } else {
      setIsRecording(false);
      if (isPaused) {
        setIsPaused(false);
      }

      if (mediaRecorderRef.current) {
        mediaRecorderRef.current.stop();
      }
    }
  };

  const handlePauseResume = () => {
    if (!isPaused) {
      mediaRecorderRef.current.pause();
    } else {
      mediaRecorderRef.current.resume();
    }
    setIsPaused((prev) => !prev);
  };

  const handleDelete = () => {
    setIsRecording(false);
    setIsPaused(false);
    setRecordedChunks([]);

    mediaRecorderRef.current = null;

    if (mediaRecorderRef.current && mediaRecorderRef.current.state === "recording") {
      mediaRecorderRef.current.stop();
    }
  };

  const handleSend = () => {
    if (recordedChunks.length) {
    setIsRecording(false);

    const audioBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: "audio/wav" });
    const file = new File([audioBlob], `voicenote_${new Date().toISOString()}.wav`, {
      type: "audio/wav",
    });
    reply([file]);
  }
  };

  return (
    <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center" spacing={2}>
      {isRecording ? (
        <>
          <IconButton onClick={handlePauseResume}>
            {isPaused ? <PlayArrow /> : <Pause />}
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDelete}>
            <Delete />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton onClick={handleSend}>
            <Send />
          </IconButton>
        </>
      ) : (
        <IconButton onClick={handleOnClick}>
          <Mic />
        </IconButton>
      )}
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this. Thank you.